# Debugger tool for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, debugging, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-restserver

I would like to develop API calls using `Codeigniter`. To view the `GET/POST/DELETE` requests came recently, I would like to have one `Debugging Tool`, like `Yii2 - Debugger`.

`PF Below for Yii-Debugger`
[image]

> Please help me with any `Codeigniter Debugger` tool which shows 10-50
>   recent requests, which holds the `DB requests` too.

I know about `DebugBar` that holds the current page data.

Answer (score 1):

I guess just enabling the profiler should help (**single request**).

In controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

More on profiler configuration: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/profiling.html#enabling-and-disabling-profiler-sections

**UPDATE:**

For logging **all/multiple requests** and having a dashboard, this lib should probably help: https://github.com/lonnieezell/codeigniter-forensics. I have no personal experiance with it, but it sounds like it does the trick. It also has a debug bar.

Comment: That Sounds Good. But `Profiling` will be displayed at the bottom of the page & that too for the currently loaded page. I want to see all the past 10 requests triggered by my application. Thaks for the response :)

Comment: @Prabhukiran I updated the answer.